# How to name the import / export packages in Java?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I have an *export / import* routine which becomes bigger and I decided to split up the packages into two smaller.

I tried to use `org.yourcompany.business.export` ...works fine! Unfortunately the opposite package with the name `org.yourcompany.business.import` is not possible to use due to the reserved keyword `import` in Java.

How do you name your *import / export* packages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write separate importer/exporter for this

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 11):

We're using exporter/importer.

Or maybe you want to use something like exchange.in and exchange.out, since that's normally the purpose of an importer/exporter - to exchange data.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably go with `importpkg` / `exportpkg` or `businessimport` / `businessexport` just to stick to the name "import", if that is the word best describing the content of the package. An alternative would be to follow the naming convention for really long identifiers, and drop a vowel in end: `imprt`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question that was asked :-)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `lib` or `api` or `util` for libraries.  Something which indicates what is being imported

Packages are designed for importing so the word in a package is somewhat redundant.

Comment: No no... I think you don't get me, maybe due to the bad explanation. I have a package that does import business logic, as reading XML into a the persistence layer or something else, a default import/export behaviour. So I want to name it `import` but this isn't possible. So I'm searching for another name!

Comment: How about loader/saver, reader/writer, or just have one presistance package. I find it very useful to have import/export functionality together in the same class/file to ensure one does the opposite of the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend exp0rt imp0rt in order to look like java renames (class into clazz)

Comment: I'd give this -1, but it would be a waste of a rep point to bother downvoting such grossness.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use the abbreviation of the words. This would be something like `imp` and `exp`.
Or if you have given the imp/exp functionality a name, you could use that as the package name, like `if.myinterfacename`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, import is a [keyword in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), you will have to think of another name for your package.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm searching for a neat name.

Comment: errr... he knows that and asked for alternative names

Comment: You have to name it otherway, keyword usage in package names are not encouraged.